# Error in r: undefined columns selected

Tags: r

I was trying to do a partition plot, and I used the following codes:

```
install.packages('klaR')
library(klaR)
partimat(Type~. , data = training, method = "lda")
partimat('Type'~. , data = training, method = "qda")
```

R gave me this error code:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(m, xvars) : undefined columns selected
```

and my data is like this

```
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   178 obs. of  13 variables:
 $ Alcohol             : num  14.2 13.2 13.2 14.4 13.2 ...
 $ Malic acid          : num  1.71 1.78 2.36 1.95 2.59 1.76 1.87 2.15 1.64 1.35 ...
 $ Ash                 : num  2.43 2.14 2.67 2.5 2.87 2.45 2.45 2.61 2.17 2.27 ...
 $ Alcalinity of ash   : num  15.6 11.2 18.6 16.8 21 15.2 14.6 17.6 14 16 ...
 $ Magnesium           : int  127 100 101 113 118 112 96 121 97 98 ...
 $ Total phenols       : num  2.8 2.65 2.8 3.85 2.8 3.27 2.5 2.6 2.8 2.98 ...
 $ Flavanoids          : num  3.06 2.76 3.24 3.49 2.69 3.39 2.52 2.51 2.98 3.15 ...
 $ Nonflavanoid phenols: num  0.28 0.26 0.3 0.24 0.39 0.34 0.3 0.31 0.29 0.22 ...
 $ Proanthocyanins     : num  2.29 1.28 2.81 2.18 1.82 1.97 1.98 1.25 1.98 1.85 ...
 $ Color intensity     : num  5.64 4.38 5.68 7.8 4.32 6.75 5.25 5.05 5.2 7.22 ...
 $ Hue                 : num  1.04 1.05 1.03 0.86 1.04 1.05 1.02 1.06 1.08 1.01 ...
 $ Proline             : int  1065 1050 1185 1480 735 1450 1290 1295 1045 1045 ...
 $ Type                : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

Please let me know how to solve it!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read [How to Create a Complete, Minimal, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your post. Also, use `dput()` to post a subset of data so others can use the data to help answer your question.

Comment: Why do you use `'Type'` the second time? Try just `Type`

Answer (score 0):

There is no `Type` variable in the [UCI Machine Learning Wine data set](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/wine). The classification variable is `class`, and it is the first column in the data set.

```
# data source: UCI ML Repository Wine data
# https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/wine 
library(klaR)
colNames <- c("class","alcohol","malicAcid","ash","acalinityOfAsh",
              "magnesium","totalPhenols","flavanoids","nonflavanoidPhenols",
              "proanthocyanins","colorIntensity","hue","od280.od315OfDilutedWines",
              "proline")
wine <- read.csv("./data/wine.csv",header=FALSE,col.names=colNames)
wine$class <- as.factor(wine$class)
partimat(class ~ alcohol + malicAcid, data=wine, method="lda",plot.matrix=FALSE)
```

...and the output:

[image]

Comment: I changed the wine class name into "Type" and I am trying to put LD1 on the x axes and LD2 on the y axes.

Comment: # Data partition
set.seed(555)
ind <- sample(2, nrow(wine),
              replace = TRUE,
              prob = c(0.6, 0.4))
training <- wine[ind==1,]
testing <- wine[ind==2,]
```
```{r}
# Linear discriminant analysis
library(MASS)
linear <- lda(Type~., training)
linear
attributes(linear)

Comment: Above is the data partition codes I used for LD1 and LD2. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I could fix it by changing the name of my varibles. In my data set I had a variable whose name had a blank space at the beginning. The program could not recognize it and that triggered the error. I removed that blank space and the problem disappeared.